# Binding CTRL+Right and CTRL+Left in tmux to mimic bash behaviour

Tags: bash, tmux

Under bash, if I use the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> or the combo <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> within a whitespaced string, the cursor will jump from word-to-word, either left or right. Under `tmux` this behavior is not present. I've tried using `unbind C-Right` as well as `C-Left` in my `/etc/tmux.conf` to no avail. Is there another way?